# How do you regenerate aspx.designer.cs in VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I am having an issue with my aspx.designer.cs file not auto updating. I am using VS 2013.
- I've tried to delete the designer file and rebuild. NO JOY.
- There is no option to convert to web project. (it's vs 2013 and the project is already a web project.
- searched Microsoft blogs for a solution and Microsoft doesn't even have a solution i can find.

If anyone has a verified way to force this file to update or regenerate, please let me know. Having to manually add my controls to this file is just PAINFUL!!!

Comment: Please be more specific on the question at hand?

Comment: This synchronization bug has been around since VS 2003...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally, just open the **ASPX** file and save <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> solves the problem.

The worst case you can delete the **individual** xxx.designer.cs, and recreate it by using **Convert to Web Application**

***NOTE:*** do not delete all designer.cs files; instead you just need to delete the one which is out of sync.

### Visual Studio 2012

[image]

### Visual Studio 2013

**Convert to Web Application** is moved under **Project.**

[image]

Comment: Convert to Web Application recreates the file but it is still missing half of the controls

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this problem was with VS2008 and the solution was to restart VS and add or remove the controls all over again.